# Complex Optimistic Updates: How to Handle More Than Just Binary-like Elements

Tags: redux, architecture, user-experience, operational-transform, optimistic-ui

I want to build an optimistic ui, in which I can perform all CRUD operations. For example a todo app in which a user can add, update and delete todo items.

However I cannot find any resource that discusses more than just adding items. For example:

- https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/optimistic-updates
- https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v2/performance/optimistic-ui/

[Other articles](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/11/true-lies-of-optimistic-user-interfaces/#:%7E:text=Apply,pattern.) even suggest not to use optimistic updates if the server response has more than two states (e.g. success, failure).

**Can someone point me to any documentation, tutorials or papers that deal with some of the following things? Or a website which has implemented this successfully?**

Some problems I have when queueing requests:

1. Rollback

- User adds todo 1
- POST request 1 is send
- User makes lots of changes
- The following http requests are queued and wait for the 1st to finish
- Request 1 fails
- We roll back to original state

User lost all his changes

2. Wasted Bandwidth

- User adds todo 1
- POST request 1 is send
- User adds todo 2
- POST request 2 is queued
- User deletes todo 2
- DELETE request 3 is queued
- POST request 1 completes
- POST request 2 is made
- DELETE request 3 is made

We did not have to send request 2 and 3

Instead of queuing the requests, I could also debounce the requests and send a transaction log
or just the current state to the backend. Then the backend could figure out the minimum of required database updates.

**Maybe there already are some of these diffing algorithms?**

Comment: Why not just refetch the current value from the server after a change? Optimistic updates are meant to be temporary assumptions, overwritten by acurate data from the server. Also, in RTK-Query a rollback is a patch that will only change certain properties back and only if they have the "after-patch-value".

Comment: Where do the docs mention after-patch-value?

Comment: They don't go deep into the `.undo` functionality, but internally it uses [`immer` patch sets](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/patches/). I'm not entirely sure about the "old value" comparison tbh. You can watch the actual patchsets happening in the Redux Devtools.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I can take some hints from collaborative editing like Google Docs:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation
- https://davidwalsh.name/collaborative-editing-javascript-intro-operational-transformation

Incredible visualisation:

- https://operational-transformation.github.io/